# Get column name from a query result

Tags: php, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

Is it possible to get column name from a query, for example:

```
SELECT name AS EmployeeName FROM wh.employee
```

Is it possible to get EmployeeName in the return results. My current PHP Code:

```
$result = $this->bigQueryService->jobs->getQueryResults($this->projectId, $jobId)
$rows = $result->getRows();
if ($rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
         /** @var \Google_Service_Bigquery_TableCell $cell */
         foreach ($row["f"] as $cell) {
             print $cell->getV();
         }
    }  
}
```

Basically, I want to get the EmployeeName from the query results, is this possible?

Comment: In the generic BigQuery API, it's in queryResult.schema.fields. I'm not sure if the PHP library has a method for that, though. I couldn't find anything that mentioned a schema object in github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am playing with Go right now so my very simplified example is in Go:

```
fields := resp.Schema.Fields
for i :=0 ; i < len(fields); i++ {
  field := fields[i].Name
  fmt.Println(field)
}
```

Check [schema of the result](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults#schema) for more details

I am not PHP person, but I think it should be something like

```
$fields = $result->getSchema()->getFields();
$fieldNames = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $fieldNames[] = $field['name'];
}
```

Comment: Spot on: getSchema()->getFields() is the function that I need.
You can also use $field->getName() instead of $field['name']